# Python: Caching a 251mb hash in memory

Tags: python, django, caching, hash, python-3.5

I am building a webapp using django and I deal with large excel files (about a million rows) that I parse into a hash for faster calculations and manipulations. I want to cache the hash, but the hash is 251mb in size and I don't think memcache allows you to cache such large variables. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I should deal with this? I'm open to ways other than caching, too.

Comment: Parsing an Excel file into a hash for faster calculations and manipulations? Could you tell a bit more about it?

Comment: @Elmex80s I have a bunch of functions to be run on the data that require a fast look up to execute. I have company_id and parent_id columns and I might have to look for all company_ids with the same parent_id and see if certain columns in the all the companies match etc. and I would run such functions on every row in the excel file.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but why not load the Excel file in memory with the xlrd module or the pandas package? The xlrd module will give you plain lists with values you can reshape yourself. The pandas package will give you DataFrames which is a very powerful data structure to deal with (very large) tables like yours.

Comment: @Elmex80s That's a great suggestion! I will definitely look into pandas but again, will that solve the issue of caching? If the end-user sends an http request after a while, will I have to re-create the structure or does pandas provide a way of caching it?

Comment: I think you need to tell us more about your problem. I also think that if you have a hash of over 250 MB then something went wrong, hashes are not supposed to be that large.

Comment: @Elmex80s It's a client-server infrastructure. So, when a user uploads a csv file, I store a copy on the server. When the user wants to run some rules on the csv file, I load the file, create a hash and run the rules using the hash. If the user wants to run the rules again, I load the file again, create the hash again and run the rules. I want to avoid having to load the file each time as the file is roughly 100mb and it takes 1-2mns to load the file. If I could cache it on the server and just load it from the cache each time, it would save the process a lot of time.

Comment: I do not know a magic Python module which does all the work for you. Therefore I think you have to program this by yourself. So you have to store temporary data on the hard drive or in memory and at every request check if the data is already there. Next to that you have to handle the limit of temporary data. I would say you store a max of say 1000 intermediate results. About the hash, if your 100 MB file gives you a + 250 MB file hash then you should change a few things.

Comment: Thank you. Redis is working fine for now and I also tried pickle to save the hash and reuse it and it seems to work fine. DataFrame also seemed pretty cool. I have an ending question though, why is it that my hash is twice the size of xlsx file? I don't have any repetition in my hash. It's just {0: [cellvalue1, cellvalue2....], 1: [cellvalue1, cellvalue2...], 2...}.

Comment: _why is it that my hash is twice the size of xlsx file_ I do not know, sorry.

Comment: @Elmex80s No problem! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not married to memcached, Redis has a maximum value size of 2GB per key. As long as you're using Django's built-in caching layer, then it's a drop-in replacement after setting up the Redis server and reconfiguring your caching settings.

See also: https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis